# How to change string into a QuickFix message?

Tags: python, quickfix, fix-protocol

I am trying to read my FIX logs and to parse them with the cracker that I wrote in python. However, this does not work because in my cracker I have calls like `message.getHeader()` which are QuickFix  methods. They unsurprisingly return an error:

`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'getHeader'`

The logs are all strings, but the cracker is embedded within QuickFix and so uses QF methods. Is there any way to take the string and transform it into a QF message so I can just call `crack(message)` on it, or do I have to rewrite my cracker for this special case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way that I do it in C# is to read tag 35 to see what message type I need to create.  Then, I create that message type, and use the setString method to populate it.  Something like this:

```
if (line.Contains("35=8"))
{
    message = new QuickFix44.ExecutionReport();
}
else if(line.Contains("35=AS"))
{
    message = new QuickFix44.AllocationReport();
}
 . . . . and so on

message.setString(line, true, dictionary);
application.fromApp(message, sessionId); //The cracker takes care of it from here
```

where dictionary is my data dictionary.  Is a similar method available in the Python bindings?

Comment: @Wapiti that's unfortunate, I was hoping you were going to say you had found a better way :-).

Answer (score 3):

The following code should work.

```
import quickfix as qfix
import quickfix44 as q44
message = q44.ExecutionReport()
message.setString(input_string, True, qfix.DataDictionary('CustomDictionary.xml'))
```

'message' object will be updated in place and you should be able to use it as a quickfix Message object

Comment: Thanks a lot, that saved me! Not using a Data Dictionary with a repeating group was completely messing up the message I was recreating from the original FIX message... Out of curiosity, how did you know to pass `True` and the DataDictionary as the second argument? Where is the documentation for that? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The following also works and doesn't require prior knowledge of message type.

```py
import quickfix as fix

string = "8=FIX.4.49=24735=s34=549=sender52=20060319-09:08:20.88156=target22=840=244=948=ABC55=ABC60=20060319-09:08:19548=184214549=2550=0552=254=1453=2448=8447=D452=4448=AAA35777447=D452=338=954=2453=2448=8447=D452=4448=aaa447=D452=338=910=056"

data_dictionary = fix.DataDictionary("FIX44.xml")
message = fix.Message(string, data_dictionary, True)

print(message.toXML())
```